# How can I get an IOS devices manufacturer?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to get the IOS device manufacturer in Flutter? I need to get it somehow.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

Comment: I am just using that package, but the manufacturer option does not appear among the options (at least in IOS).

Comment: Apple delegates manufacturing to other companies, but for all intents and purposes you can consider all iOS devices to be manufactured by Apple, Inc.

No manufacturer information is exposed in any iOS API that I know of

Comment: In that case, should I manually put the Apple name in the IOS manufacturer?

Comment: Is allowed anybody else to manufacture iOS device? -as far as I know, only Apple.